# Is (remote) code execution possible by maipulation of Dataoffsets in some compresed Formats?

Tags: assembly, exploit, machine-code

I had the Idea, that an decoder could be used to execute machine code, by manipulating input data.
When an decoder decompres data with wordbooks (like Lempel-Ziv) it could be possible to change an offset to a value near eip instruction pointer and copy a jmp or call instruction there, with the hoped result that machine code of the inputdata will be executed.

I know this is a strange question, but I don't know whether this principle would be implementable.

Comment: Obviously a decoder that checks for valid compressed data won't let you store outside the output array. Any such exploit would depend on a vulnerability in the decoder (a bug, unless it was intentionally written to "trust" the input and not do any sanity checking).  Also note that normal modern systems execute code from read-only pages, so you can't just overwrite code directly unless the program was built strangely (with a read+write .text section)

Comment: BTW, this hand-wavy question about classes of exploits (not programming details of making one work) is probably better suited to https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It is a possible attack in principle, but there are too many countermeasures for this to be viable in practice.  I do recall stuff like this being used to hijack embedded systems, though.  A more likely attack is using out-of-bounds dictionary accesses to read arbitrary data in the attacked processes.  This is possible if the decompressor doesn't check its reads.